# Fetch API with change event

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Is it possible to make an API call when a select box value changes? The idea is just to have a select box full of different years and when you select a new year the results on the page change. My Code:

```
const yearSelector = document.querySelector('#yearSelect');

function getConstructorStandings(year) {
    fetch(`http://ergast.com/api/f1/${year}/constructorStandings.json`, {
        "method": "GET",
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists.length > 0) {
            const { ConstructorStandings } = data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0];
            ConstructorStandings.forEach((C) => {
                const team = C.Constructor;
                const constructor = new Constructor(team.name, C.points, team.constructorId);
                constructor.getConstructorScore();
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
yearSelector.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    getConstructorStandings(e.target.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. I attach an example of what your code could look like. The concept is simple, so every change event that your select executes, it will emit an event and call your api.

```js
const character = document.getElementById('character');

character.addEventListener('change', () => {
  fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${character.value}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>{
      $('#data').html(`
        <p>Name: ${res.name}</p>
        <p>Status: ${res.status}</p>
        <p>Gender: ${res.gender}</p>
        <p>Species: ${res.species}</p>
        <p>Location: ${res.location.name}</p>
      `)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="character">
  <option selected></option>
  <option value="1">Rick</option>
  <option value="2">Morty</option>
  <option value="3">Summer</option>
  <option value="4">Beth</option>
</select>

<div id="data" style="margin: 2rem;">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the reason my code wasn't working was because I was passing a string to the function instead of a number.